# constructor en java

Tags: java

¿Cuándo proporciona Java automáticamente un constructor predeterminado y cuándo no?

Comment: Consejo: siempre debemos usar las etiquetas relevante al problema

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

El compilador va a agregar un constructor predeterminado siempre que no exista al menos un constructor declarado en el código fuente, por ejemplo:

```
public class Hola {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println("Hola");
    }
}
```

El código anterior, después de haber sido compilado, genera un siguiente archivo `.class`, que decompilado se ve así:

```
class Hola {
        Hola() {} // <- Aquí, se agregó un constructor predeterminado

        public static void main(String... args) {
                System.out.println("Hola");
        }
}
```

**Nótese que se agregó el constructor predeterminado**.

Pero si por ejemplo cambiamos el código fuente a

```
public class Hola {
    private Hola() {
        System.out.println("Soy el único constructor");
    }
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println("Hola");
    }
}
```

El archivo decompilado se ve exactamente igual al código fuente que escribimos.

```
public class Hola {
    private Hola() {
        System.out.println("Soy el único constructor");
    }
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println("Hola");
    }
}
```

Esto es porque el compilador detecta que **sí** hay por lo menos un constructor en la clase, y por lo tanto no crea el constructor por defecto.

Esto sucede aún así, si el constructor es `private`, como en el ejemplo anterior. De hecho esto se explica en el libro *Effective Java 3rd ed.*, y es algo que a veces se puede hacer si no queremos que una clase sea instanciada desde otras clases.

Si simplemente no agregaramos el constructor, el compilador lo agregaría, haciendo posible así, que la clase se pueda instanciar desde otras clases.

**Nótese que no es `java` quien proporciona automáticamente el constructor por defecto, sino el compilador de `java` (`javac` en la mayoría de casos), eso sucede en tiempo de compilación, no en tiempo de ejecución**

Comment: Solo un apunte, el contrustor por defecto siempre incluye el modificador `public`.